# hstore sending hidden field as array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hstore

I have one old software built by developer where they are using hstore to store values. But web page load dynamically many different styles and make following form hidden values

```
  <input type="hidden" name="style[name]" value="FANCY">
  <input type="hidden" name="style[name]" value="SIMPLE">
```

Now it is only sending one parameter of last line, but I have to save this in hstore like following

```
[{"name":"FANCY"},{"name":"SIMPLE"}]
```

but it is saving just one

```
{"name":"FANCY"}
```

I also tried to add empty `name="style[name][]` but it then add multiple values in name but not like I want. So how can I pass multiple values in hidden field to save in hstore. As I realized it is doing correct, but how come I send above multiple parameters.

Comment: You have to use `name="style[name][]`. Using `name="style[name]"` the way you do, will never ever work. Can you give an example of what using `name="style[name][]` actually returns and an example of what you want it to be?

Comment: well I think I got solution using `style[][name]` but it is also giving a lot error in controller, the `style="style[name][]` was returning `"name"=>["FANCY", "SIMPLE"]`

Comment: You do realize that you can't store an array of hashes in an hstore column? Its a data type that includes one or more key value pairs and where each key must be unique. If you declare an hstore with duplicate keys, only one will be stored in the hstore and there is no guarantee as to which will be kept. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/hstore.html

Comment: Or is this input supposed to create multiple rows in the database? Anyways the question does not make sense - like for example "So how can I password multiple values in hidden field" . Uhm do you mean pass? You need to tells what the actual task you are trying to accomplish is and focus less on the input which is just a tiny piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I have option to add multiple styles on a design, so my form add ajax styles with many more values not just name, it can have 1-6 different styles with many different values. So ajax is showing all values and creating one form with hidden values, now I want to save all these values in hstore.